# Fast retrieval of data from json object using xpath

Tags: javascript, json, xpath

I have a very large data set that may contains thousands of records hierarchy is

```
records
 ->record1
   ->main_record
   ->minor_record
        ->fields
->record2
    ->main_record
        ->data_records
            ->fields_records
                ->fields
```

This hierarchy can be even more rested depending upon the input file and it may contains hundreds for records like `record1` `record2`, here one thing I must mention that data is not sorted at level.

Now lets suppose I want to find `fields` in `fields_record` than XPath will be

```
record2/main_record/data_records/fields_records/fields
```

one way to find is to loop whole dataset and find desired record which is not affordable, the way I am using for searching data is:

```
function main() {
  var dataset = getDataFromService();
  getResult(dataset, xpath);
}

function getdataset(dataset, nametosearch) {
  for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
    if (dataset[i].name == nametosearch) {
      return dataset[i];
    }
  }
}

function getResult(dataset, xpath) {
  if (xpath.indexOf('/') > -1) {
    var splitArray[] = xpath.split("/");
    for (var i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
      dataset = getdataset(dataset, splitArray[i]);
    }
    return dataset;
  } else {
    getdataset(dataset, xpath); //else part to get records at root level
  }
}
```

With the above mentioned code I can get data I want to know is this way efficient? If not what would be the better option for getting data using XPath?

Comment: XPath is to get data from XML, but not from JSON.

Comment: @t.niese i know that ,i want to know what would be the strategy to get data using xpath?? and is my above mention code is efficient??

Comment: @Mark Look into [Defiant.js](http://www.defiantjs.com/)

Comment: @har07 thanks ,please tell me is above mentioned code is efficient ??

Comment: Then it is a XPath like technique. You alway should take care when using names of techniques. While one can assume from the given code that you might be award that it is just XPath like, you still should mention it. Anyway you might want to look at this: [JSONPath](https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [JSONPath.](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)

Eaxmple:
Json:

```
{
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName" : "doe",
     "age"      : 26,
     "address"  : {
         "streetAddress": "naist street",
         "city"         : "Nara",
         "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
     },
     "phoneNumbers": [
         {
           "type"  : "iPhone",
           "number": "0123-4567-8888"
         },
         {
           "type"  : "home",
           "number": "0123-4567-8910"
         }
     ]
 }
```

Path:$.phoneNumbers[:1].type
Result:"iPhone"

Comment: whenever you paste JSON or code wrap it with "`" tag, or use "{}"  option from toolbelt - code will be formatted (thus more readable)